# CDP not Tracking user Interactions

Tags: cdp

I am working with Sitecore 10 and CDP. I have created a custom web template in Sitecore CDP and trying to track all user Activity. Previously it worked fine, but now it doesn't track the user activity.
I have added the below script in to the layout file and track the Identity event from custom Template API.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Define the Boxever queue
  var _boxeverq = _boxeverq || [];
  _boxeverq.push(function () {
      var viewEvent = {
          "browser_id": Boxever.getID(),
          "channel": "WEB",
          "type": "VIEW",
          "language": "EN",
          "currency": "EUR",
          "page": window.location.pathname,
          "pos": "xxx"
      };

      //Add UTM params
      viewEvent = Boxever.addUTMParams(viewEvent);
      // Invoke event create
      // (<event msg>, <callback function>, <format>)
      Boxever.eventCreate(viewEvent, function (data) { }, 'json');
  });
  
  // Define the Boxever settings
  var _boxever_settings = {
      client_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', //Replace with your client key display in screen shot
      target: 'https://api.boxever.com/v1.2', // Replace with your API target endpoint specific to your data center region
      cookie_domain: 'xxx.dev.local', //Replace with the top level cookie domain of the website that is being integrated
      pointOfSale: "xxxx", //Replace with newly created POS
  };

  // Import the Boxever library asynchronously
  (function () {
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.async = true;
      s.src = 'https://d1mj578wat5n4o.cloudfront.net/boxever-1.4.8.min.js';
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
  })();
</script>
```

I am getting following error in console
[image]

Comment: Your script works fine for me (even on localhost) with my own client_key. So, I just can guess that problem is with your client_key.

Comment: Can you check all variables are passed as expected? Primarily check clientkey, cookie domain, and pointofSale matches. You can dynamically also pick POS = _boxever_settings.pointOfSale and browser_id: Boxever.getID(). You can also refer to working copy from [CDP Events JS](https://github.com/MadhavJ/CDP-Deep-Dive/blob/main/App/js/sitecore-cdp.js)